# CSS Selector for selecting an element that comes BEFORE another element?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm working on a login page for my website and I want to bold the label that comes **before** the input box when the text box gains focus. Right now I have the following markup:

```
<label for="username">Username:</label>
<input type="textbox" id="username" />

<label for="password">Password:</label>
<input type="textbox" id="password" />
```

I can use the adjacent selector to select the label **after** the text box, but I can't select the element before it. I can use this CSS selector rule, but it only selects the label after, so when the username text box gains focus, the password label becomes bold.

```
input:focus + label {font-weight: bold}
```

Is there anything I can do to make this work? I know JavaScript could be used to easily do this, but I'd like to use a purely CSS-based solution if possible, I just can't figure out a way to do it.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It would be possible to use the 'adjacent sibling selector' if the `input` was before the `label`.  Just put the `input` before the `label`, and then modify the layout to put `label` before the `input`.  Here's an example:

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
    input:focus + label {font-weight: bold}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div style="direction:rtl">
        <input type="text" id="username" />
        <label for="username">Username:</label>
    </div>
    <div style="direction:rtl">
        <input type="password" id="password" />
        <label for="password">Password:</label>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

(It's kind of a hack, I would personally use javascript to do this)

```css
input:focus + label {font-weight: bold}
```

```html
<form id="form1" runat="server">
  <div style="direction:rtl">
    <input type="text" id="username" />
    <label for="username">Username:</label>
  </div>
  <div style="direction:rtl">
    <input type="password" id="password" />
    <label for="password">Password:</label>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: This is still good accessibility wise. They can be in any order but always always always use the 'for' and 'id' attributes.

Comment: How portable is the input:focus? which browsers don't like it?

Comment: input:focus does not work in IE7 (I just checked.)  It works in firefox.  Not sure about other browsers.

Comment: Unfortunately, the above code does not work in Safari 3.2.1. I didn't take the time to understand what is wrong. Firefox, as already noted is just fine.

Comment: Instead of changing the direction, you could float the input to the right.

Comment: Like "Guillermo Guitiérrez" said, you can use `#form1>div>* {float: right;}` CSS to change the order of the elements which is much better than text direction changing. The `direction: rtl;` code also produces errors like putting the colon ":" before the word "Password". Although this can be fixed with `direction: ltr;` CSS added to the label tags, using "float: right;" CSS for the label and input tags avoids all of this text direction issue.

Comment: >  I would personally use javascript to do this .. 
Not an answer to the question.

Answer (score 41):

The [CSS Selectors 4 Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/#subject) provides a syntax for defining the "subject" of a selector by using a `!`. As of early-2016, this is not available in any browser. I'm including this because it will be the correct way to do this using pure CSS once browsers implement this syntax.

Given the markup in the question

```
<label for="username">Username:</label>
<input type="textbox" id="username" />

<label for="password">Password:</label>
<input type="textbox" id="password" />
```

This CSS would do the trick.

```
label:has(+ input:focus) {font-weight: bold}
```

Of course, this assumes browsers actually implement the subject selector and that there are no bugs related to how this syntax works with the `:focus` pseudo-class.

Comment: Update: About May 2014, no effect in FF 28.

Comment: Update: Mid April 2015, no effect in FF 37 (got here again by coincedent ^_^ )

Comment: "*Is there a “previous sibling” CSS selector?*" question comment at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817792/is-there-a-previous-sibling-css-selector#comment44596668_15503444 says that the specification allows previous sibling selection with `previous:has(+ next)`. So there seems to be a working solution probably in the current specification.

Comment: Whoops, the `:has` selector is currently, at time of writing, a W3 draft and not in the specification. For details see my comment http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817792/is-there-a-previous-sibling-css-selector#comment60563696_15503444.

Comment: This is actually the answer. Unluckily as of now (2022) only Safari implements this selector outside pre-release versions. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has

Answer (score 8):

There's no selector that will give you the previous element using CSS..

You will need to use javascript to handle what you're after.

Comment: "*Is there a “previous sibling” CSS selector?*" question comment at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817792/is-there-a-previous-sibling-css-selector#comment44596668_15503444 says that the specification allows previous sibling selection with `previous:has(+ next)`. So there seems to be a working solution probably in the current specification.

Comment: Whoops, the `:has` selector is currently, at time of writing, a W3 draft and not in the specification. For details see my comment http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817792/is-there-a-previous-sibling-css-selector#comment60563696_15503444.

Answer (score 5):

Use this selector:

```
label[for=username]
{
font-weight: bold
}
```

this will select the label that has the value 'username' in the attribute 'for'

Comment: Will this select the label when the text box has focus though?

Comment: no, this will only select the element

Comment: I think the question was: will label become bold when input has focus?

Comment: Oops! thanks mouviciel. I've removed my comment just in case.

Answer (score 5):

Floating the input element to the right, achieves correct element order without changing order of "Username" and ":" in the label text that you get with direction:rtl.

```
<style type="text/css">
    form {text-align: right;}
    input:focus + label {font-weight: bold}
    input {float:right; clear:right;}
</style>
<form>
    <div>
        <input type="text" id="username" />
        <label for="username">Username:</label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="password" id="password" />
        <label for="password">Password:</label>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: In my opinion, this is a better solution than changing text direction. For a better alignment, I would add: div {overflow: auto;} in the stylesheet.