# Separate CSS for label checkbox to label input

Tags: html, css

I have used label for with both input textboxes:

```html
<label for="Username">Username</label>
<input id="Username"  type="text" value="">
```

and checkboxes/radioboxes

```html
<label for="Live">System is Live</label>
<input id="Live" name="Live" type="checkbox" value="false">
```

The trouble I have is how do I specify different css for the labels for different input types.

If I do a generic label css:

```css
label {
    color: #00a8c3;
    line-height: 20px;
    padding: 2px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 160px;
}
```

I find I either end up with unaligned checkboxes or badly positioned textboxes.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could add classes to the labels. For example:

```
<label for="Username" class="textbox-label">Username</label>
<input id="Username" type="text" value="">

<label for="Live" class="checkbox-label">System is Live</label>
<input id="Live" name="Live" type="checkbox" value="false">
```

Then use the class values in CSS:

```
label.textbox-label {
 /*some styles here*/
}

label.checkbox-label {
 /*some styles here*/
}
```

Alternatively, if you had the labels after the inputs, you could select like this:

```
input[type="text"] + label { 
  /*some styles here*/
}

input[type="checkbox"] + label { 
  /*some styles here*/
}
```

Comment: Also labels can have an id.  So if you want a specific style for one label.

Answer (score 6):

You could write css selector like this will work:

```
label[for=Username]{ /* ...definitions here... / } 

label[for=Live] { / ...definitions here... */ }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write your css selector like this:

```
label[for=Username] 
label[for=Live]
```

You may also have a look at this thread: 
[CSS Selector for selecting an element that comes BEFORE another element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492786/css-selector-for-selecting-an-element-that-comes-before-another-element)