# How can I select all <div> elements that are placed immediately BEFORE <p> elements?

Tags: css

We know that with `div + p` in CSS we can select all `p` elements placed immediately after `div` elements, but can we do the opposite?

Example: [jsfiddle.net/6afkbsfL/2](https://jsfiddle.net/6afkbsfL/2)

Comment: Looks very similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492786/css-selector-for-selecting-an-element-that-comes-before-another-element

Comment: Or this: [stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

Comment: Thanks! I didn't see those questions in the suggestion area :/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `~` selector.
try `p ~ div`.
See [CSS Selector](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) for more options.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use JQuery, you can try `$("div+p").prev()` to get all the div placed immediately before a `p`