# CSS selector for ALL elements with SAME CLASS after and before current element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was looking here: [CSS Selector for selecting an element that comes BEFORE another element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492786/css-selector-for-selecting-an-element-that-comes-before-another-element)
...but wasn't able to find a correct answer for my issue.

***Here is a fiddle example:*** https://jsfiddle.net/Munja/bm576q6j/3/

```
.test:hover, .test:hover + .test
```

With this, when I :hover element with .test class, I achieved to change style for current element with .test class and first next element with .test class.

***What am I trying to achieve?***

When I select any row/column (e.g agent 2), I want to apply same style for ALL elements with that same class (*.test* in this case).

[image]

If it is not possible to achieve this with css only, *** I am willing to accept and other good solution.***

Thank you.

Comment: Is this what you want? https://jsfiddle.net/bm576q6j/4/

Comment: @BasvanStein Ah, sorry. What I need is not to apply same css for all classes in tbody.. I need to apply it only for particular elements with .test class in tbody.

Comment: copied the comment as answer :)

Comment: What do you mean by 'selecting' a row or column? Should the user simply hover over it, or click on it?

Comment: @DavidThomas let's say that user should only hover it. And every time user hover any element with .test class, ALL .test classes in this table will have new style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after waiting for several more hours, I have decided to use JavaScript solution mentioned in answer from @BasvanStein. Posting it here as answer, to make things easier for someone else with same issue.

Here is a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Munja/bm576q6j/15/

```
var elms = document.getElementsByClassName("test");
var n = elms.length;

function changeColor(color) {
    for(var i = 0; i < n; i ++) {
        elms[i].style.backgroundColor = color;
    } 
}
for(var i = 0; i < n; i ++) {
    elms[i].onmouseover = function() {
       changeColor("red");
    };
    elms[i].onmouseout = function() {
       changeColor("white");
    };
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your specific case you can use

```
tbody:hover > .test { 
    background: green;
}
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bm576q6j/4/

Note that if you add more classes in the same `tbody` it will not give what you want. Check also this question: [Hover on element and highlight all elements with the same class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12786810/css-hover-on-element-and-highlight-all-with-same-class)

Comment: Ah, sorry. What I need is not to apply same css for all elements in tbody.. I need to apply it only for particular elements with .test class.

Comment: Check, in that case see the link. You can use the `~` operator to get the next siblings, but if you want them all you need to switch to javascript as described in the answer of the linked question.

Comment: Hm I was able to use JS from comment in provided question and it helped me (https://jsfiddle.net/Munja/bm576q6j/13/) but I am going to leave question open for some time so we can see if someone maybe have pure css solution.. Ty

Comment: Sure no problem, multiple questions say it is not possible but lets see what people come up with I am curious as well!