# CSS Selector for div with class ::before

Tags: html, css

I have a Vaadin 14 app which creates an HTML page that contains multiple "

Screenshot from Chrome shows the relevant page section:
[image]

I've tried this with and without the "::before":

```
.vaadin-button-container ::before {
    justify-content: left !important;
}
```

I have also tried

```
.vaadin-button-container::before {
    justify-content: left !important;
}
```

According to Chrome dev mode this style is never applied to the vaadin-button-container.

This css selector stuff is driving me nuts!

Comment: Could you please check [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492786/css-selector-for-selecting-an-element-that-comes-before-another-element)?

Comment: Remove the space before `::before`

Comment: Yes I have tried it without a space before "::before" and that has no effect.

Answer (score 1):

This should work..

```css
.vaadin-button-container::before { 
justify-content: flex-start; }
```

Please, remove space and try..

Comment: I have tried without the space before "::before" and that has no effect.